# How to simulate Enter key at gtk.entry to save info

Tags: python-2.7, gtk, gtkentry

I want one or several gtk.Entry reply to a button created by me (gtk.Button) instead of a enter key.

I´m using Python 2.7

Is it possible?

Comment: You can just call `entry.activate()` from the buttons "clicked" signal handler

Comment: Thank you @jku.Could I make a modified class, which would also be sensitive to the focus switch to another gtk.Entry

Comment: Sure, take a look at the [focus-out-event](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-focus-out-event) (but notice the atypical event mask requirement). I'd say that more often you'd want to look at the "notify::text" signal (which fires every time the entry "text" property changes) though.

Comment: I create a new Entry class adding this line: 
self.connect('focus-out-event', self.onEntryActivate )
thanks @jku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a new Entry class adding this line:  `self.connect('focus-out-event', self.onEntryActivate )`